# Word count using fold

Tags: scala

How can a list of words be counted into a Map structure where Int is the count and String is the current word.

I'm attempting to use a fold for this but this is closest I've got :

```
val links = List("word1" , "word2" , "word3")
links.fold(Map.empty[String, Int]) ((count : Int, word : String) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1)))
```

Which causes error :

```
value getOrElse is not a member of Int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the signature of fold, you can see that

```
links.fold(Map.empty[String, Int]) ((count : Int, word : String) => ???)
```

won't compile

fold on `List[A]` has type `fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1`

That's not something you can use; `Map.empty[String, Int]` is not a subtype of `String`

What you need is `foldLeft`: `foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B`

Your `A` is `String`. Your `B` is `Map[String, Int]`, but then in your second parameter list you have `(Int, String) => ???` That doesn't conform to the signature. It should be `(Map[String, Int], String) => Map[String, Int]`

A solution immediate presents itself:

```
(map: Map[String, Int], next : String) => map + (next, map.get(next).getOrElse(0) + 1)
```

Putting it all together, you'll have

```
links.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])
((map: Map[String, Int], next : String) => map + (next, map.get(next).getOrElse(0) + 1))
```

Comment: @Martjin your code "  links.fold(Map.empty[String, Int])
  (map: Map[String, Int], next: String) => map + (next, map.get(next).getOrElse(0) + 1)" causes compile time error "missing arguments for method fold in trait TraversableOnce; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied functionq"

Comment: You forgot replace `fold` with the `foldLeft` in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most efficient, but the clearest way for me would be:

```
val grouped = links groupBy { identity } // Map[String, List[String]]
val summed = grouped mapValues { _.length } // Map[String, Int]

println(grouped) // Map(word2 -> List(word2, word2), word1 -> List(word1))
println(summed) // Map(word2 -> 2, word1 -> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a foldLeft:

```
val links = List("word1" , "word2" , "word3", "word3")
val wordCount = links.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])((map, word) => map + (word -> (map.getOrElse(word,0) + 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where some of the abstractions of a library like [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) or [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) are useful and provide a nice solution.

We can represent a word `"foo"` as `Map("foo" -> 1)`. If we can combine these maps for all our words we end up with the word count. The keyword here is *combine*, which is an function defined in [`Semigroup`](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/semigroup.html). We can use this function to combine all the maps of our word list together by using `combineAll` (which is defined in [`Foldable`](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/foldable.html) and which does the folding for you).

```
import cats.implicits._

val words = List("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c")

words.map(i => Map(i -> 1)).combineAll
// Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, a -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Or in one step using `foldMap` :

```
words.foldMap(i => Map(i -> 1))
// Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, a -> 2, c -> 3)
```